Connect to docker container inside Jenkins on server
is it possible to somehow connect to the container that I am running inside Jenkins on the server? It is impossible to connect to the server with Jenkins, and the nodes are in a different network from me. Each build has different subnets for Jenkins (apparently the build is launched on different nodes), is it possible to forward the network there? I am running a container with postgres, and I can forward a port from Jenkins to the container, but since the build is launched each time on different nodes with different subnets, I do not know how to connect to it.

Option 1: In the pipeline you can specify a specific node, to which a build should be assigned. Option 2: While the build is happening the build process can initiate a ssh connection towards an external server, and once connected successfully you can tunnel back into the container.
